# ios 5 simulator providing alert while launching

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios-simulator

Hi friends this is not related to coding question, I need to modify settings for Ios 5 simulator.Those settings are related to proxy alert,need to disable while launching the application.Please find the screen shot below shown.
[image: screen shot]  For each time running my code one alert is appearing i need to cancel or ok that alert for couple of times then only it ll disappear.Where as i am running with 4.2 simulator that alert is not appearing. can any one suggest me what is the reason for alert pop up in ios5 simulator and how to disable it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you work in a company that has firewall enabled for their internet connection...?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yes your guess is correct.But in 4.2 there is no alert appearing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSURLConnection than you can over ride it using this method....

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSLog(@"Connection did receive authentification challenge");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.while launching the application i am getting that alert.I am not using any services.

Comment: May be whatever you are using is somehow getting some data from the internet.. like a mapview or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the proxy turned on for the internet connection under Wi-Fi settings.